# Perpendicular Distance

Tags: geometry

I have a question regarding the concept of perpendicular distance. I am trying to determine the following perpendicular distance.

Can someone show me how to compute the perpendicular distance between a point $(x,y)$ and the line of equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$

Thank you

Comment: Are you in $\,\Bbb R^3\,$ ? Because if you are then $\,x^2+y^2=a^2\,$ is *not* a line in the space but an infinite cylinder of radius $\,|a|\,$ ...

Comment: Yes it's $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the question is asking for the distance from an arbitrary point $(p,q)$ to the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $a\gt 0$.

Draw the circle with centre the origin and passing through $(p,q)$. This has radius $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$. To find the nearest point to $(p,q)$ on the circle, draw the line joining the origin to $(p,q)$.

Now a picture shows that if the point $(p,q)$ is outside the circle, its distance to the circle is $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}-a$, the difference of the radii.  If $(p,q)$ is inside the circle, the distance is $a-\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$. This can be gathered into the single formula $|\sqrt{p^2+q^2}-a|$.

**Added:** Finally, because of a later question about moments of inertia, I know what the question intended to ask. We are given a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the circle with equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$.

Let $\ell$ be a line through the origin, say $cx+dy=0$. We want the distance from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $\ell$. This distance is
$$\frac{|cx_0+dy_0|}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}.$$
The problem is reasonably [well-discussed here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) and in many introductions to linear algebra. Note that the fact that $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the circle has no direct impact on the expression for distance.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Probably all started when I took the $(x,y,z)$ of the original post at face value, and gave as a hint the reduction of the problem to the plane.

Comment: Which was a valid interpretation of the problem. Upvoted.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have a problem with this. When I replace u and v with there respective parametric equations $a\cos t $ and $a \sin t$, I obtain for the distance 0. Is it normal?

Comment: The parametric equations for $u$ and $v$ are $u=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\cos t$, $v=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\sin t$. But I expect you want to parametrize the points $(x,y)$ on the circle of radius $a$. Then you are right, and we want to minimize $\sqrt{(u-a\cos t)^2+(v-a\sin t)^2}$. You can do it that way, using techniques from the calculus, though we can bypass calculus. If you are interested, I can solve the problem that way. It is quite a bit longer than the simple solution that Robert Millikan and I gave.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wait a second. In the problem They say to find the moment of inertia about the diameter. What does that mean? I will have to use the expression of the distance when the point is inside the circle ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas What do you think ?

Comment: What are the parametric equations of u and v then ? using only t and a I suppose

Comment: In your problem, the numbers $u$ and $v$ (what I called $p$ and $q$) are **fixed** given numbers. So the variability is in the circle. If we minimize, it is by considering these.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok. But I still don't understand how to change the expression with the parametric form. You shouldn't have introduced these new variables. I am more confused now

Comment: I had to introduce new symbols, your choice of $(x,y)$ both for the point we are given and for the variables $x$, $y$ of the equation of the circle leads to problems.

Comment: @AndreNicolas So you mean the distance IS zero ?

Comment: I just saw that you have a question about moment of inertia. It is best not to ask it in a comment. You could post such a question. The wording should be as close as possible to the question you were asked.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you mind if I repost the question and providing me with a complete answer. I really need it. I am unable to follow at all

Comment: I don't mind. But if you post the same question as before, someone will want to close it as a duplicate. The main difficulty seems to be that the problem has never been stated using correct language. It started with the $(x,y,z)$, that meant $3$-dimensions.

Comment: @user43418: If the given point $(p,q)$ happens to be on the circle, then sure, the distance will be $0$. But in all other cases it won't. Robert Millikan and I both have given explicit formulas for the minimum distance.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I posted it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374527/moment-of-inertia-of-a-circle

Answer (score 1):

You have used $x,y$ twice, so I will call the point $(u,v)$.  The equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$ describes a circle centered at the origin with radius $a$.  The distance from the origin to $(u,v)$ is $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$.  As long as $(u,v)$ is outside the circle, the distance to the circle will be $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}-a$.  If $(u,v)$ is inside the circle, the distance will be $a-\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$.  You can combine these into one formula if you like by using the absolute value function, getting $|a-\sqrt{u^2+v^2}|$.

Comment: I have a problem with this. When I replace u and v with there respective parametric equations $a\cos t $ and $a \sin t$, I obtain for the distance 0. Is it normal?

Comment: @user43418:  because of the factor $a$, you are putting $(u,v)$ on the circle.  The distance *should* be zero.  Try $(3a\cos t, 3a\sin t)$ and the point will be $3a$ from the origin, so the distance to the circle will be $2a$

Answer (score -1):

That equation is not a straight line, so there's no unique perpendicular distance - each point on the cone has a different normal space. But since it's a cone, you can still find two specific rays perpendicular to the curve which pass through the point, and the angle of those rays about the XY plane is unique. Since you only need to compute the length of the line segment that creates, you need to know two things:

The distance from the origin of the point $(x_p, y_p, 0)$. Consider this to be $(x_p, y_p, a_p)$'s position along the line in the XY plane through the origin which runs through its shadow.

The equation for the height of the line on the cone as a function of distance from the origin. The cone being rotationally symmetric, you can take the case where y=0. This is just $a=\pm x$.

This gives you the new point $(d_p,a_p)$ and new pair of lines $a=\pm x$.

From here you can compute the normal perpendicular distance from $(d_p,a_p)$ to these two lines, and choose the smaller of the two.

The perpendicular distances from the new lines to the new point are given by the lengths of the vector rejections of the point $(d_p, a_p)$ from the vectors $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, which are unit vectors in the direction of the two lines.

EDIT: Since you say the curve is in the plane, the perpendicular distance is in the same way really a difference of radii. So take $abs(||(x_p, y_p)||-a)$, where $||v||$ is the length of a vector $v$.

Comment: BTW. We are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ not $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Could you include the computation in your answer please?

Comment: For the perpendicular distance from the new lines to the new point?