# Moment of inertia of a circle

Tags: geometry, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics, polar-coordinates

A wire has the shape of the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$. Determine the moment of inertia about a diameter if the density at $(x,y)$ is $|x|+|y|$

Thank you

Comment: Are you having trouble setting up the integral or evaluating it?

Comment: @vadim123: I think he/she wants the second one.

Comment: I am having trouble settIng it up, particularly determining the perpendicular distance

Comment: If you use a "nice" diameter, like the one where $y=0$, the perpendicular distance is given by $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$.

Comment: @vadim123 could you do the entire computation just to make sure that what I did is correct?

Comment: @user43418: It would be more helpful for you if you shared what YOU did and we were able to give you detailed commentary and suggestions relevant to your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a small segment of the wire, going from $\theta$ to $\theta +d\theta$. The length of the small segment is $a \,d\theta$. The density varies, but is approximately $a|\cos\theta|+a|\sin \theta|$.

Take a particular diameter, say with rectangular equation $y=(\tan\phi) x$, or better, $x\sin \phi -y\cos\phi=0$. The perpendicular distance from $(a\cos\theta,a\sin\theta)$ to this diameter is $|a\cos\theta\sin\phi -a\sin\theta\cos\phi|$.
So for the moment of inertia, we need to find
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \left(a|\cos\theta|+a|\sin \theta|\right)\left(a\cos\theta\sin\phi -a\sin\theta\cos\phi\right)^2a\,d\theta.$$
The integration is doable, but not easy. Special cases such as $\phi=0$ or $\phi=\pi/4$ will not be too hard.

**Remark:** The perpendicular distance from a point $(p,q)$ to the line with equation $ax+by+c=0$ is 
$$\frac{|ap+bq+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
There is a reasonably good discussion of the formula in Wikipedia.

Comment: Do you find $4a^3$ ?

Comment: What do you find as the final result ?

Comment: I have not done the integration. My intuition may not be good, but I think the answer might depend on $\phi$, because the density is not uniform.

Comment: Can I ask you another question? It's here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374514/polar-coordinates-on-a-set-t 

It's very shot. I think I know the answer but I'm just want to make sure

Comment: By the way, I don't see that the answer would involve $a^3$, because of the strangeness of the density function. It is linear in $a$, and so is the length of a segment with angle $d\theta$. Then multiplying by the square of the distance gives us another $a^2$ factor.

Comment: Yeah it's actually $4a^4$